# Exception Parsing Copy of NSData to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I have a callback method when a socket receives data like this...

```
+ (void) dataReceived:(NSData *)data {
    NSData *dataCopy = [data copy];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataCopy encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"msg: %@", msg);
}
```

I can see in the debugger that both `data` and `dataCopy` contain the correct string data. The `dataCopy` is made without an issue but when the `msg` line is called, I blow up w/ this.

> 2015-04-02 15:45:10.179 Sandbox[15218:539849] -[__NSCFString bytes]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9c71447870 2015-04-02
>   15:45:10.184 Sandbox[15218:539849] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString
>   bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9c71447870'

I don't understand, I can see the data is correct, I thought making the copy is what prevents access to overwritten memory. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your "delegate" method gets called with a NSString instead of a NSData. Copying the received object won't help you in this case, as you're just copying a string into another string. You'll need to dig deeper and see why dataReceived: doesn't receive the expected NSData object.

Comment: D'Oh. I think you're right.